# How get both image name and src on single onclick?

Tags: javascript

Is  this possible, get both image name and src on single click of an image?

I am new to javascript and php.

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 function SetImageName(strName)
 {
 document.getElementById("ImageName").value = strName;
 }
 </script>

 <div id="Images">

 <img src="images/image1.jpg" name="image1.jpg" onclick="SetImageName(this.name)"/></a>
 <img src="images/image2.jpg" name="image2.jpg" onclick="SetImageName(this.name)"/>

 </div><input type="hidden" value="" id="ImageName" name="ImageName"/>
```

Comment: Have you considered using jQuery? or is your preferred solution required in pure js?

Comment: why do you need `src` and `name`?  In your example, `name` is contained within `src`.

Comment: David Hoerster. yes... My intention is to echo the image again in same page.... Is this possible?

Answer (score 10):

Is it possible? Of course.

In your html markup:

```
onclick="SetImageName(this)"
```

And then in your JS:

```
function SetImageName(imgElement) {
    var theName = imgElement.name;
    var theSrc = imgElement.src;
    // etc.
```

That is, when you call `SetImageName()` pass the reference to the clicked element itself with `this`, rather than just its name with `this.name`. Then within your function you can access any and all of its properties as needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the 'src' of the image using this function:

```
 document.getElementById("imagename").src
```

So your code would be:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function SetImageProperties(control)
    {
        // Populate hidden fields with properties of the control
        document.getElementById("ImageName").value   = control.name;
        document.getElementById("ImageSource").value = control.src;
    }
 </script>

 <div id="Images">

 <img src="images/image1.jpg" name="image1.jpg" onclick="SetImageProperties(this)"/>
 <img src="images/image2.jpg" name="image2.jpg" onclick="SetImageProperties(this)"/>

 </div><input type="hidden" value="" id="ImageName"   name="ImageName"/>
 </div><input type="hidden" value="" id="ImageSource" name="ImageSource"/>
```

By passing

```
 this
```

instead of

```
 this.name
```

you are passing a reference to the whole DOM object.  You can then use each property separately as shown in your modified code above.

Answer (score 0):

When the user will click the image the function `SetImageName` will invoked by:

```
onclick="SetImageName(this)"
```

Meaning:

```
<img src="images/image1.jpg" name="image1.jpg" onclick="SetImageName(this)"/>
```

`SetImageName` Function implementation you will get the name and src of the image by `image.name` and `image.src`